# Defining URL Query String Parameters in AWS::Serverless::Api SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, aws-sam

How do I define and validate URL Query String Parameters for an AWS::Serverless::Api in a SAM template?

They don't seem to be mentioned in the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html

Just to be clear this is what I am talking about
[image]

Comment: Please add to your question your template yaml/json

Answer (score 3):

The URL Query String Parameters is defined in [AWS::Serverless::Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-requestparameter.html) rather than AWS::Serverless::Api using `RequestParameters` property.

All parameter names must start with `method.request` and must be limited to `method.request.header`, `method.request.querystring`, or `method.request.path`.

For example to define `email`, `name` in URL Query String Parameters and `Authorization` in HTTP Request Headers u can do the following:

```yaml
Events:
 ApiEvent:
   Type: Api
   Properties:
     Path: /path
     Method: get
     RequestParameters:
       - method.request.querystring.email:
           Required: true
           Caching: false
       - method.request.querystring.name:
           Required: true
           Caching: false
       - method.request.header.Authorization:
           Required: true
           Caching: true
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your response is in another resource, AWS::ApiGateway::Method.

Check the documentation (search for Request Parameters):

> The request parameters that API Gateway accepts. Specify request parameters as key-value pairs (string-to-Boolean mapping), with a source as the key and a Boolean as the value. The Boolean specifies whether a parameter is required. A source must match the format method.request.location.name, where the location is querystring, path, or header, and name is a valid, unique parameter name.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#cfn-apigateway-method-requestparameters